# MX Keys and Mouse keep disconnecting if connected to a USB Hub

Tags: 20.04, usb, logitech-unifying

I recently got MX Keys and Mouse. Both have their own unifying receiver. When I connect the unifying receivers to USB ports (USB 3.0) of the laptop, it works absolutely fine. But if I connect the unifying receivers to USB Hub (USB 3.0), either keyboard or mouse or both disconnects after sometime. I have to unplug and plug again the receiver/s to make keyboard and mouse work again.

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 on my laptop. So, after doing some searches, I set usbcore.autosuspend=-1, but it didn't solve the problem.

Any idea about this problem and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

2 solutions:

1. Connected the dongles to a USB-C hub which connects to a thunderbolt port. No connection problem but there was a new problem with this solution. The problem was the batteries of both MX Keys and Mouse were getting drained quickly like within 7 - 8 days.
2. Connected the dongles to a USB 2.0 hub which connects to a USB-C hub which connects to the thunderbolt port of the laptop. No connection problem. Working good so far.